# Getter returning 0 when called from other class

Tags: java, android

I'm beginner to Android and Java, and i just saw some videos of using getter and setter method in java which worked well when i used the getter and setter method in same class. But when i set the position of an image from main class using setter method and try to retrieve it from my fragment class using getter method its returning 0. there was a similar question asked in stackoverflow which i didn't understand. Please help me out..
My main class:

```
 public class Login_Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        Login login = new Login();
        Register register = new Register();
    ImageButton LoginB;
        ImageButton RegisterB;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.login_register);
            FragmentManager fmanager = getFragmentManager();
            LoginB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            RegisterB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Reg_button);
            LoginB.setOnClickListener(this);
            RegisterB.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Positions pos = new Positions();
            pos.setLIpos(LoginB.getY());
            pos.setRIpos(RegisterB.getY());

            FragmentTransaction transaction = fmanager.beginTransaction();
                    switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.login_button:

                transaction.add(R.id.Parent, login, "Loginf");
            transaction.addToBackStack("Login");

                break;
            case R.id.Reg_button:
                    transaction.add(R.id.Parent, register, "registerf");
                transaction.addToBackStack("registerf");

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            transaction.commit();

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }
```

My fragment class:

```
public class Login extends Fragment implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    EditText UN, Pass;
    View loginimage, loginusing, loginlayout;

    // Login_Register Lg=new Login_Register();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View login = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UN = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.UsernameL);
        Pass = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.PassswordL);
        loginimage = login.findViewById(R.id.LoginImage);

        loginusing = login.findViewById(R.id.loginusing);
        loginlayout = login.findViewById(R.id.LoginLayout);
        loginimage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        UN.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
        Pass.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
        Positions poss=new Positions();
        float f=poss.getLIpos();
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(loginusing, View.ALPHA, 0,1).setDuration(1000).start();

        return login;
    }
}
```

Class with setter and getter methods:

```
public class Positions {
    private float LIpos=0;
    private float RIpos=0;

    public Positions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public float getLIpos() {
        Log.i("allalalla", ""+LIpos);
        return LIpos;
    }
    public void setLIpos(float lIpos) {
        LIpos = lIpos;
    }
    public float getRIpos() {
        return RIpos;
    }
    public void setRIpos(float rIpos) {
        RIpos = rIpos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting the float you instantiate your class. That creates a default class with floats initialized to 0.

```
Positions poss=new Positions();
float f=poss.getLIpos();
```

If you want to save the floats between different instances of this class then make the floats static:

```
private static float LIpos;
private static float RIpos;
```

---

Alternatively you can preserve a reference to the instance where you save the floats and pass it your fragment, or your fragment could fetch that instance from your activity directly:

```
public Position pos;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pos = new Positions();
        ...
}
```

Then in your fragment fetch the position element and get the floats:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    float LIpos = ((Login_Register)getActivity()).pos.getLIpos();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Suggesting people use static variables is probably not helpful in the long run.  Java is an OO language, and statics are a non-OO wart on the language.  Avoid them were possible.

Comment: @StephenC updated my answer with 2 more proper solutions, shown an example of one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a confusion between the notion of a class and an instance. A class is a simple contract or definition if you will, of a designed object in terms of attributes and functionality. An instance is the real *active object*, the one that you apply operations on during runtime. Now when you write:

```
Position pos = new Position();
```

In the heap memory it is allocated the memory for the particular instance you point to by the `pos` reference. If in another place you type:

```
Position poss = new Position();
```

It crates one more instance of the class `Position` which is referenced by `poss`. The `poss` and `pos` have nothing to do with each other and their internal attributes may have totally unrelated values. I believe this explains why you cannot see the same attribute value for different instances.

As for how to deal with this, @user3249477 gave some options from which i recommend the second.

Comment: I didn't know that creating more instance of class can lead to more heap memory allocation... The above answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing in wrong way. You are creating an instance of Position class in both Activity and Fragment.

Try to create an method inside Fragment which will receive position object which you have been set inside activity like below:

Your activity onClick

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Positions pos = new Positions();
        pos.setLIpos(LoginB.getY());
        pos.setRIpos(RegisterB.getY());

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fmanager.beginTransaction();
                switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.login_button:

            transaction.add(R.id.Parent, login, "Loginf");
        transaction.addToBackStack("Login");
        login.setImagePosition(pos);

            break;
        case R.id.Reg_button:
                transaction.add(R.id.Parent, register, "registerf");
            transaction.addToBackStack("registerf");
            register.setImagePosition(pos);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        transaction.commit();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Your Fragment

```
 class Login extends Fragment implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {

  EditText UN, Pass;
  View loginimage, loginusing, loginlayout;

// Login_Register Lg=new Login_Register();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View login = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UN = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.UsernameL);
    Pass = (EditText) login.findViewById(R.id.PassswordL);
    loginimage = login.findViewById(R.id.LoginImage);

    loginusing = login.findViewById(R.id.loginusing);
    loginlayout = login.findViewById(R.id.LoginLayout);
    loginimage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    UN.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
    Pass.getBackground().setAlpha(50);

    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(loginusing, View.ALPHA, 0,1).setDuration(1000).start();

    return login;
}

public void setImagePosition(Positions pos){
    Positions poss=pos;
    float f=poss.getLIpos();
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and the above answer taught me one more method of avoiding unnecessary creation of instance of a class..